# Present or introduce my ideas

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

What is the difference between this two sentences.

> 1. I am going to **present** my solution notes to my  boss.
> 2. I am going to **introduce** my solution notes to my boss.

"Present" seems to me as something showed "outside" and "introduced" as something that I can involve sb in "inside".

Answer (score 1):

If you *present* your ideas it suggests a certain formality, like you might stand up at a podium and give a lecture on them. You can also use this if you're going to be in an one-on-one setting, but want to suggest a bit of formality about the discussion.

If you *introduce* your ideas, you're emphasizing that your boss hasn't heard these ideas before. This is the first time you'll tell her anything about them except maybe that you've had some ideas on whatever subject it is.

It's possible that both words could be suitable for the same situation, but each will emphasize a certain aspect of the situation more than the other.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that present is the correct term to use for a business setting. To me it's not just more formal, it's more professional in general. I think that it carries more weight to it, in the sense that the solution has been thought out. Introduce sounds more like sales-speak.

Comment: I spoked to my friend, he has adviced me to use "put forward" in this kind of situations.

Comment: @user63306, *put forward* is also common.